# how to truncate or remove or delete the string after ":" in Groovy?

Tags: string, groovy, split

My list is like this below and am not sure its a list or any but it is like this below

```
apple:sdasdsddssd
banana:sdds
carrot:sdsadsdsdsdsdsdds
```

I want to remove the strings after ":"

my output should be like this below

```
apple
banana
carrot
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `takeWhile` on Strings:

```
def inputs = [
    'apple:sdasdsddssd',
    'banana:sdds',
    'carrot:sdsadsdsdsdsdsdds'
]

def result = inputs*.takeWhile { it != ':' }
```

Result will be a list containing the strings `apple`, `banana` and `carrot`

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [`split` docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.8/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence)).

`split` returns an array. You are printing that array instead of the first element of the array.

```
groovy:000> list = ['apple:ccxxc', 'banana:sasasa', 'carrot:sdsdsdsddds']
===> [apple: ccxxc, banana:sasasa, carrot:sdsdsdsddds]
groovy:000> for (i in list) {
groovy:001>   def one = i.split(':')
groovy:002>   println(one[0])
groovy:003> }
apple
banana
carrot
```

You might want to consider some form of mapping instead of just printing out the value, or a more functional-looking approach, depending on what you're actually doing.

Updated based on a completely different question as per comments:

```
groovy:000> list = ['apple:ccxxc', 'banana:sasasa', 'carrot:sdsdsdsddds']
===> [apple:ccxxc, banana:sasasa, carrot:sdsdsdsddds]
groovy:000> for (i in list) {
groovy:001>   println(i.replaceAll(':(.*)', ''))
groovy:002> }
apple
banana
carrot
```

Comment: isnt any method in groovy to remove the strings after ":"?

Comment: @rick Sure, `"foo:bar".replaceAll(":(.*)", "")` (and others; string replacing in both Java and Groovy is trivially searchable on the web) but that's not what you originally asked. My snippet follows your original code, the only difference is that it works.

Comment: if i do like that i am getting each character in a separate line a/n p/n p/n l/n e/n

Comment: @rick Then you're doing something wrong. I've updated the answer based on the completely-different question.

Comment: @rick, according to the result you have string and not a list. replaceAll should help you with multiline flag.